# inline div is not in center of another div/section on server but on localhost its fine

Tags: html, css

Here is the website and the part where im having issues
https://kas-test.000webhostapp.com/volonteri.html

Top part where i used inline tag works but its not in center like the bottom part, also on kontakt.html.. everything is off its course while when i run the same code on localhost everything looks fine..

Here is picture of localhost: [image: picture]

Its perfectly in center.. why?

Comment: Okay I removed width from .container and now its fine.. but that still got me wondering why did it work fine on localhost and its not working fine on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I DO recommend to you start using a grid system ([bootstrap has a good one](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#how-it-works)). Also blockquote isn't a good way to make a "left border", you can accomplish it by using `border-left: 5px solid black`

But if you only want to "hotfix" your code, you can update it by doing:

```
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 30px); // new
  max-width: 500px; // new
  margin: 15px;
  float: left;
}

blockquote {
  text-align: justify;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px; // new
}
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
<blockquote>
<div style="padding-left:30px;">
                    ‘‘Sveukupni rad i funkcioniranje udruge bazira se na radu volontera. Volonteri su jedna od najvažnijih i nezaobilaznih karika u cjelokupnom programu rada udruge. Minimalna dobna granica volontera za uključivanje u rad udruge je 14.godina. Nakon što izrazi želju da želi volontirati, volonter ispunjava pristupnicu te nakon toga potpisuje volonterski ugovor gdje su regulirana prava i obaveze volontera, te dobiva volontersku knjižicu u koju se svake godine upisuju odrađeni sati volontiranja. Volonteri su dužni držati se svim pravila i propisa o ponašanju što je definirano u volonterskom ugovoru. Volontirati se može na više različitih načina a najčešći su uključivanje u provedbi terapijskog jahanja, pomoć oko skrbi za konje, pomoć kod održavanja rekreacijskog jahanja, pomoć pri čišćenju i održavanju okoliša i opreme, sudjelovanje na raznim kulturno-zabavnim manifestacijama na kojima udruga sudjeluje, pomoć oko promidžbe rada udruge, konjičkog sporta, reklamiranja, upoznavanja građanstva s aktivnostima udruge itd. Ovisno o potrebama i mogućnostima organiziraju se radionice za volontera gdje se obučavaju i osposobljavaju za što efikasniji rad. Više puta kroz godinu organizira se druženje volontera a u skladu s mogućnostima i edukacija i usavršavanje izvan udruge.”
<h6><i>Dominik Tomaš</i></h6>
</div>
```

Try to adjust the padding-left value to recenter it properly, since you're using border-left for the `<blockquote>` at the same time you had your text inside it, that's why it keeps the text sticking on the border, what i did is I tried to put the texts in a different element, but still in the inside the div. Check this if it helps you.